# Remove part of a polygon

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS 3.10.1, and I am trying to fix invalid geometry in a number of polygons.

This polygon (orange) surrounds a road, but also has a sliver going straight across. As a fairly new QGIS user, I don't know how to get rid of it - I have messed around with the Editing tools, but can't find anything that works.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried v.clean? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141753/grass-processing-tools-via-qgis-v-clean-snap-chdangle-and-rmdangle

Comment: I haven't tried v.clean - I'm having trouble getting Grass up and running, and am overall intimidated by the documentation I've found so far. I was wondering if there is another way to do it, but maybe I just need to put more time into solving my Grass-related issues.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out - under the Advanced Digitizing Tools, I activated the "Delete Part" tool and then clicked on the sliver. All fixed!