# Repairing geometry using QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, geometry, qgis-processing

I'm looking for a roughly equivalent tool in QGIS to the **Repair Geometry Tool** in ArcGIS Desktop. When I run some common vector processing tools in QGIS, I occasionally run into invalid geometry errors and have yet to find a quick/easy fix that doesn't involve manual editing.

Is there an automated process that I can use?

Comment: Hi, welcome to GIS S.E! This kind of question has been asked and answered here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112687/fixing-geometry-validity-errors-in-qgis. You could also try the `Fix geometries` tool if the solutions in that thread don't suit your needs.

Comment: v.clean? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141753/grass-processing-tools-via-qgis-v-clean-snap-chdangle-and-rmdangle

Comment: There is a standalone utility to fix this kind of problems, and I find it to be very reliable.  It is called Shapechk by Andrew Williamson.  
  
It can be downloaded from this link:  
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/7824/93912

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=fix%20geometries#fix-geometries